# Viewport render image does not work correctly

Tags: rendering

If I render viewport im wireframe, solid and material preview shading, it works correctly. But if I render viewport in render shading, there are only lines without material. In other scenes it works correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean **Viewport Render Image**? If it is, works fine for me.

Comment: @bao007fei do you did this in my file? In other files it works for me, but not in this. I press (button on top) View > Viewport Render Image (in render shading mode), and pie is hidden.

Comment: I checked again. Eevee works fine, Cycles doesn't work. In any blender file:(